# A bit value verification

Tags: c

I want to verify two bits (for example the bit number 3 and 5) values of a uint8
if their value is 0, I want to return 1

```
uint8 a;
if ((a & !(1<<3)) && (a & !(1<<5)))
{
    Instructions..
}
```

Is this code correct ?

Comment: No, because `a` is not initialized.

Comment: Bit a bit negation is `~` not `!`

Comment: Do some testing before asking, and you will soon find this condition is not correct.

Comment: no, `if ((a & ((1<<3) | (1<<5)) == ((1<<3)|(1<<5))) ...`

Answer (score 4):

No, your code won't work in way that you want. `!` operator results only in `0` or `1` and info about actual non-zero bit is lost anyway. You may use something like this:

```
if(!(a & ((1 << 3) | (1 << 5))) {
    /* ... */
}
```

At first stage you are creating mask with `|` operator. This mask has non-zero bits only at positions that you are interested in. Then this mask is combined with tested value via `&`. As result you get `0` only if value has zero bits at tested positions. And then just inverse `0` to `1` with `!` to obtain true condition.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct.

The `!` operator is boolean NOT, not a bitwise NOT.

So, if you want to check if bits 3 & 5 are both zeroes you should write:

```
uint8 a;
...
if (!(a & (1<<3)) && !(a & (1<<5)))
{
    Instructions..
}
```

Further optimisation of the expression in `if` is possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is trivial if you don't attempt to write it as a single, messy expression. There is no advantage of doing so - contrary to popular belief, mashing as many operators into a single line is actually very bad practice. It destroys readability and you gain no performance benefits what-so-ever.

So start by creating a bit mask:

```
uint8_t mask = (1<<3) | (1<<5);
```

(The parenthesis are actually not needed, but not everyone can cite the C operator precedence table in their sleep, so this is recommended style.)

Then check the data against the mask:

```
if(data & mask) // if any bit contains value 1
  return 0;
else            // if no bit contains value 1
  return 1;
```

Which, if you will, can be rewritten as a boolean expression:

```
return !(data & mask);
```

The complete function could look like this:

```
bool check_bits (uint8_t data)
{
  uint8_t mask = (1<<3) | (1<<5);
  return !(data & mask);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `a` actually *is* initialized, then the expression will not work as you expect. The logical not operator `!` gives you a one or a zero (boolean true or false), which you then use in a bitwise and operation. That will not give you the correct result.

I suppose you mean to use the bitwise complement operator `~` instead, as in `~(1 << 3)`. Not that it would work anyway, as that will just check that any of the other bits in `a` is non-zero.

Instead check if the bit is one, and then turn around the logic using the logic not operator `!`, as in `!(a & 1 << 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression is false, you should not negate the masks this way and you must ignore other bits so don't use a negation. Simply:

```
(a & (1<<3)) + (a & (1<<5))
```

gives 0 if both are 0s.

Answer (score 0):

No. `!` operator does logical negation, and since `1<<3` is not zero, `!(1<<3)` is zero. It means `a & !(1<<3)` will always be zero and therefore the condition will never be true.

I think masking is one of good ways to do what you want to do.

```
uint8 a;
/* assign something to a */
return (a & ((1 << 3) | (1 << 5))) == 0;
```

`a & ((1 << 3) | (1 << 5))` is a value in which the 3rd and 5th bit (0-origin) of `a` keep their original value and all other bits is turned to zero. Checking if the value is zero means checking if all of the bits to check are zero while not careing other bits. `==` operator will return 1 if two operands are equal and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test for some combination of `BIT_A` and `BIT_B` (or whatever number of bits you can have) You can do this:

```
#define BIT_A (1 << 3)
#define BIT_B (1 << 5)
...
#define BIT_Z (1 << Z)

...
/*      |here you put all bits           |here you put only the ones you want set */
/*      V                                V                                               */
if (a & (BIT_A | BIT_B | ... | BIT_Z) == (BIT_A | ... | BIT_I | ...))
{
    /* here you will know that bits BIT_A,..., BIT_I,... will **only**
     * be set in the mask of (BIT_A | BIT_B | ... | BIT_Z) */
}
```

as with `a & (BIT_A | BIT_B | ... )` you force all bits not in the set to be zero, so only the bits in the set will conserve their values.  With the second mask, you generate a bitmap with only the bits of the set you want to be set (and of course the bits that are not in the set forced zero) so if you compare both values for equalness, you'll get the expected result.

## NOTE

As an answer to your question, the particular case in which you want all the bits equal to one, is to make both masks equal.  For your case, you want to check if **both bits are zero**, then your test is (the second mask has no bits set, so it is zero):

```
if (a & ((1 << 3) | (1 << 5)) == 0) { ...
```

(All bits in the second mask are zero as the required mask, and both, the third and the fifth bits are set in the first mask)  This can be written in a more compact form as (you can see it written as):

```
if (!(a & 0x28)) { /* 0x28 is the octal for 00101000, with the bits you require */
```

## WHY THE CODE YOU WROTE IS NOT CORRECT

First you mix logical operators like `!` with bitmasks, making `!(1<<3)`to eval to `0` (`1<<3` is different of `0` so it is true, negating gives `0`) and the same for the `!(1<<5)` subexpression.  When you mask a with those values makes you get `a & 0 ==> 0` and `a & 0 ==> 0` and anding both together gives `0 && 0 ==> 0`. So the result value of your expression is `0 -- false` always, independent of the original value of `a`.